# What are the boundaries around pads in KiCad PcbNew and what are their functions?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, footprint

I am learning to design PCBs in KiCad. Right now I am using footprints I found online.

In PcbNew I find there is a boundary surrounding each pad. In footprints found in KiCad, these boundaries don't overlap with the boundary of the adjacent pad. In a few footprints I downloaded from the Internet, I find the boundaries overlapping. In the below screenshot of the PcbNew components, green arrows are the overlapping boundaries and pink arrows are non-overlapping boundaries.

What is the function of these boundaries? Is there a problem if they overlap? If yes, what are those problems and how can I edit them  so that they don't overlap?

[image]

Comment: It's probably the soldermask boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boundaries you are referring to are visual aids associated with constraints.

These constraints are there to help you with regards to the fabrication technology or other creepage considerations.

Such settings are associated with the PCB project, not the footprint.
[image]

With the default board configuration (0.2mm) clearance and a standard SOT23 footprint, it can be seen that there is overlap between pin1-pin2 and pin2-pin3 boundary.

**NOTE: overlap of such outlines are fine, it is when the outline of one touches the copper of another... then there is a DRC violation**

Now the rules can be changed and as you can see, changing it to 0.1mm reduces these rings and now they don't overlap
[image]

You can then create named constraints where different nets might require larger clearance consideration (controlled impedance? higher voltage)

[image]

Once you start assigning netclasses the new (v5.99) constraints manager permits you to write rich design constraints.

NOTE:  do not shrink the clearance downto a value that permits the layout to be completed, shrink it to the value it need and this is typically downto your fabricators capability w.r.t. copper thickness.

A recent 1oz card I did had the DEFAULT clearance set to 0.13 (with isolated nets with 0.3mm) while an associated 3oz card had the DEFAULT clearance set to 0.26mm